# how to update the column of one table while using the value from column of another table when using insert into statement in vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have googled related to "Insert into..." query, but i never find solution related to my problem.
MY query is i want to insert the value from one table to another meanwhile i also have to update the value of one additional column in table1(CBWCFARTGSADJ) using the value of table2(CBWCFAMISUPLOAD).

I have following access query:

```
Insert INTO CBWCFARTGSADJ (VENDOR,AMOUNT,LOCATION,DEPSLIPNO,CLIENTCODE,REMARK,transaction_type) 
select
VENDOR,ADJ_AMT,LOCATION,DEPT_SLIP_NO,CLIENT_CODE,REMARKS from CBWCFAMISUPLOAD WHERE nz([ADJ_AMT],'')<>'' and nz([ADJ_AMT],'')<>'0'
```

here Im inserting value from CBWCFAMISUPLOAD but i want to update one additional column ie(transaction_type from table CBWCFARTGSADJ) 
from ADJ_AMT column from CBWCFAMISUPLOAD

ie if ADJ_AMT >0 then transaction_type will="cr" else transaction_type of 
CBWCFARTGSADJ  will "DR"

please help me out... thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: You need to run 2 queries and I guess they are independent meaning when you insert into values in table 2, the value that you want to get from table 2 and update a column in table 1 will not change? if not, then you can just run 2 separate SQL statements and you should be good.

Comment: Yup, two queries

Comment: thanks ,running two quires help me out @lbo ,@absinthe